# jar file in linked resources of eclipse indigo give "Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from <jar file path>"

Tags: java, environment-variables, eclipse-indigo

I created a path variable in eclipse and link a jar file using this path. Then adding this file to the build path. On my PC it's working fine and but it is giving following error on others PC's.
dialog box appear with message "Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from "

Basically we have different projects in eclipse that uses the same jar files, these different projects are  different module of a big project.
We need to put all jar files in a separate drive. I use the above mechanism, so whenever we move project to any other system, we just need to set the variables value, all are automatically adjusted.

Can any one tell about this problem or can give alternate solution??????

--
   Junaid

Answer (score 0):

We have solved it.
go to Window->Preferences->java->"Build Path"->"Classpath variables" and create a variable that points to the root directory of libraries.
 go to project properties->"java build path" click "add variable", select the variable you created and extend it.
This is where you can select all the jars.